# How to mock txt output?

Tags: c#, moq

I have a txt which the logic can access through a repository. I want to determine that when I call Write method from logic, the repositorys Write method is called once. My code:

```
    [Test]
    public void TestThatWriteWasCalledOnce()
    {
        Mock<IRepository> mockinstance = new Mock<IRepository>();
        LogicSaveGame logic = new LogicSaveGame(mockinstance.Object);
        //mockinstance.Setup(x => x.Write(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>())).  //???
        logic.Write(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>());
        mockinstance.Verify(x => x.Write(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once());
    }
```

When I run the test above I get the error:

```
Message: 
System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value
Stack Trace: 
XAttribute.ctor(XName name, Object value)
```

I'm really grateful for any help, couldn't find anything with google.

Edit, logicsavegame:

```
    private readonly IRepository saveGameRepo;

    public LogicSaveGame(IRepository repo)
    {
        this.saveGameRepo = repo;
    }

    public void Write(string name, string a, string b, string filename)
    {
        int ids = this.saveGameRepo.GetIds(filename);
        var xd = new XElement(
            "game",
            new XAttribute("id", ids + 1),
            new XAttribute("name", name),
            new XAttribute("hour", DateTime.Now.Hour),
            new XAttribute("minute", DateTime.Now.Minute),
            new XElement(
            "player1",
            new XElement("name", a.Name),
            new XElement(
            "player2",
            new XElement("name", b.Name),
            ));
        this.saveGameRepo.Write(filename, xd.ToString());
    }
```

Edit 2: I get the same error with 
    mockinstance.Setup(x => x.Write(It.IsAny(), It.IsAny())).Verifiable();

Comment: i think we are missing some info. can you show the logicsavegame class?

Comment: I have a generic solution for lots of similar problems without even thinking about details: I use diagnostic stream. It intercepts any output, then I can use for example my testing environment to analyse the internal stream. Diagnostic stream is a `Stream` implementation that is built on top of any other stream given by the code. You intercept the I/O, you can do anything, including watching every byte read or written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

To fix your problem pass to method call `logic.Write` concrete `string` values, for example:

```
logic.Write("name", "a", "b", "filename");
```

---

**Explanation**

The problem is not in mocking `IRepository`. The problem is how you call method `logic.Write`. You pass parameters to it using `It.IsAny<string>()`. Method `It.IsAny<string>()` returns `null` value, therefore during execution your method `logic.Write` is called with the next values:

```
logic.Write(null, null, null, null);
```

Inside method `logic.Write` you create [`XAttribute("name", name)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xattribute.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Xml_Linq_XAttribute__ctor_System_Xml_Linq_XName_System_Object_). Documentation says that this constructor requires both its parameters to be not null. In the test it is called with `null` value of the `name` variable therefore an exception `System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null` is thrown that points to the constructor `XAttribute.ctor(XName name, Object value)`. Therefore to fix the problem it is neccessary to pass to method `logic.Write` non-null string values.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfectly with a lot of string.Empty.

Answer (score 0):

I smell you forgot to set up your mock correctly before calling your `LogicSaveGame` (which is saving to XML file apparently). You may refer to this [link](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart).

Comment: this is exactly the problem, my write method is void and I can't return anything in setup